# How can i use mongoconnector in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I want to use **mongoconnector** in **kubernetes** i found this

> $ docker run -d --link=mongo:mongo --link=elasticsearch:elasticsearch
>   yeasy/mongo-connector

The question is how i can run it in **kubernetes**

Answer (score 0):

this will run docker image while kubernetes is orchestration engine. You have to upload this docker image to docker hub or have to check if it is available on docker hub.

so on Kubernetes you can run this docker images using the manifest files.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongoconnector
  labels:
    name: mongoconnector
spec:
  selector:
     matchlabels:
       name: mongoconnector
  template:
     metadata:
       lables:
         name: mongoconnector
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: mongo
         image: <DOCKER IMAGE>
```

Comment: how to link it to mongo and elasticsearch

Comment: you know how to use helm chart on kubernetes cluster ? ....you can easily find mongo and elastic search helm chart and install it...so easy way it will be

Comment: i am sharing here one gray log helm chart you can refer it it will help to understand helm....in this helm chart there is mongo and elastic search working together for graylog cluster

Comment: i have mongo cluster and elastic search cluster but how can i connect them by mongoconnector

Comment: this looks promising https://hub.docker.com/r/yeasy/mongo-connector

Comment: for ES7, this is more likely to be what you need https://hub.docker.com/r/rwynn/monstache

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example how you can run your connector as service on kubernetes cluster.

https://medium.com/devopslinks/scaling-mongodb-on-kubernetes-32e446c16b82

Comment: this document speak about mongo
but my question is how can i connect to mongo connector and elasticsearch

Comment: you have to point your elastic-search to the mongo-connector deployed on kubernetes by exposing mongo-connector to an endpoint or vice-versa, tell monog-connector your elastic-search endpoint.. based on your situation.

Comment: but how can i do that

Comment: does any doument speak about it

Comment: or can you tell me more specific details about it

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Answer (score 0):

For ElasticSearch 7 support, Monstache project looks like a good fit
https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/

They publish a docker image
https://hub.docker.com/r/rwynn/monstache